# horizontal progress bar shift between colros while loading ? for password strength verification

Tags: android

i want to change the color of progress in a horizontal progressbar while loading, example( for checking password strength, with every percentage the progressbar shows a specific color).I tried to change the color, but it changes the entire progressbar.Here what i've tried :

```
mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the colors to gradually change, or just change between a few specific colors along the way?

Comment: [link](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e8087a7474ecc5ad10db72ef3b1fae836dbff701/68747470733a2f2f73322e67696679752e636f6d2f696d616765732f657a6769662e636f6d2d6769662d6d616b6572623930636463306263666235323263622e676966)

Comment: here's the example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a nice challenge, here's what I came up with. I made a text watcher that can be attached on any EditText that updates a horizontal ProgressBar. The key here was using `progressBar.setProgressTintList` to change only the color for the progress and not the rest of the drawable.

Here's the text watcher:

```kotlin
class PasswordStrengthTextWatcher(
        private val progressBar: ProgressBar,
        private val colors: List<PasswordStrengthColor>)  : TextWatcher {

    private var lastColorIndex = 0

    init {
        // x100 to ensure they are intermediate values for animation.
        progressBar.max = (colors.size - 1) * 100
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) = Unit

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        val newIndex = getColorIndexForLength(s?.length ?: 0)
        if (lastColorIndex != newIndex) {
            // Animate progress
            ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", newIndex * 100)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
                    .start()

            // Animate color
            val currentColor = progressBar.progressTintList?.defaultColor ?: colors[lastColorIndex].color
            val colorAnim = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(currentColor, colors[newIndex].color)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
            colorAnim.addUpdateListener {
                progressBar.progressTintList = ColorStateList(
                        arrayOf(intArrayOf(0)), intArrayOf(it.animatedValue as Int))
            }
            colorAnim.start()

            lastColorIndex = newIndex
        }
    }

    private fun getColorIndexForLength(length: Int): Int {
        // Find the index of the color corresponding to a password length.
        for ((i, color) in colors.withIndex()) {
            if (length < color.length) {
                return i - 1
            }
        }
        return colors.lastIndex
    }

    data class PasswordStrengthColor(val color: Int, val length: Int)

    companion object {
        private const val ANIMATION_DURATION = 250L
    }
}
```

Or in java:

```java
public class PasswordStrengthTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 250;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private List<PasswordStrengthColor> colors;

    private int lastColorIndex;

    public PasswordStrengthTextWatcher(ProgressBar progressBar, List<PasswordStrengthColor> colors) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.colors = colors;

        progressBar.setMax((colors.size() - 1) * 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(@Nullable CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(@Nullable CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(@Nullable Editable s) {
        int newIndex = getColorIndexForLength(s == null ? 0 : s.length());
        if (lastColorIndex != newIndex) {
            // Animate progress
            ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", newIndex * 100)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
                    .start();

            // Animate color
            ColorStateList progressTint = progressBar.getProgressTintList();
            int currentColor = progressTint == null ? colors.get(lastColorIndex).color : progressTint.getDefaultColor();
            ValueAnimator colorAnim = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(currentColor, colors.get(newIndex).color)
                    .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
            colorAnim.addUpdateListener(anim -> {
                progressBar.setProgressTintList(new ColorStateList(
                        new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{(int) anim.getAnimatedValue()}));
            });
            colorAnim.start();

            lastColorIndex = newIndex;
        }
    }

    private int getColorIndexForLength(int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            if (length < colors.get(i).length) {
                return i - 1;
            }
        }
        return colors.size() - 1;
    }

    public static class PasswordStrengthColor {
        public final int color;
        public final int length;

        public PasswordStrengthColor(int color, int length) {
            this.color = color;
            this.length = length;
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use it:

```kotlin
editText.addTextChangedListener(PasswordStrengthTextWatcher(progressBar, listOf(
        PasswordStrengthColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, 0),
        PasswordStrengthColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"), 6),
        PasswordStrengthColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7f00"), 8),
        PasswordStrengthColor(Color.parseColor("#ffaf00"), 10),
        PasswordStrengthColor(Color.parseColor("#007fff"), 12),
        PasswordStrengthColor(Color.parseColor("#00af3f"), 14)
)))
```

Here's how it looks:
[image]

Comment: thank you freind, i'm wiriting my code in java, i'm not that  familiar with kotlin code, so i created the kotlin class and called it in my java code, but the first thing that i don't understand, is " listOf" and it says method call expected

Comment: I'll make it in Java in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks man, i really appreciate it, thank you , you saved my day <3

Comment: I just added it. Next time put a language tag on your question so people can know which language to use :)

Comment: thanks a lot my freind, you are the best <3 , yes yes my bad, i don't use stack frequently so that's why i'm bad lol, i will use try it and  tell you how it works.